# Symfony won't continue processing events after setting response

Tags: php, symfony

Currently i have the following event listener in symfony.

```
namespace {app-namespace}\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

use {app-namespace}\Common;

class InvalidCredentialsExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getException() instanceof Common\InvalidCredentialsException) {
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode('401');
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd assumed that symfony would pick up on then unauthorised status code and then continue processing it as if it's returned lower in the stack using the standard security firewall. Is this possible. I'd rather not be constructing urls in here.

Comment: Why should symfony continue processing if you already have a response ready?

Comment: Yes that's a fair point but if the response is a 401, i'd expect that to trigger the firewall to deal with this. The response is "ready" but there are plenty of places symfony would pick up on this before headers are actually issued.

Comment: If you want to add custom headers, you have to up the prio of your onKerelException variant. There is a way on how to do that I think, but I can't find it for you right now.

Comment: Makes no difference in this case. If i drop the prio too much it fails in catching the exception. Anything higher and still the same result.

Comment: I think you missed the status code. It's the `HTTP403` Forbidden you want, right?

Comment: No it's 401 unauthorised. I'm trying to get the firewall to trigger and send me to a login page.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed it for `HTTP400` Bad request...

Comment: Ok, my response it irrelevant then. One question though: did you miss `{app-namespace}` in `instanceof` test?

Comment: Na. That's just me obfuscating the code slightly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 2's Firewall doesn't pick up on status codes. A HTTP status code is something a webserver returns to a webclient to give some basic info on what happened with the request. It is not something an application needs internally.

I suggest you take a look at the `start()` method in [FormAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/EntryPoint/FormAuthenticationEntryPoint.php), which will give you a good example of how Symfony 2 handles this forward/redirect action.

You can mimic this in your exception listener. I suggest you inject the http-utils (service-id `security.http_utils`) and the router (service id `router`) into your listener. Use the router to get the path to the login page, and use the http-utils to create a redirect response. If you want to forward in stead of redirect, you will need the http-kernel (service-id `http_kernel`), in stead of http-utils.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did figure something like this but it gives me a much better starting point for getting what i need.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code snippet I wrote few days ago and used it successfully:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();

    $r = null;
    $req = $event->getRequest();

    if ($this->kernel->getEnvironment() == "dev") {
        return;
    }

    if ($exception instanceof RecoverableError) {
        $r = new Response($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getCode());
    }
    else if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        // Symfony's HTTP404: Not found
    }
    else if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        $r = new Response("You need to login in order to view this content.", 403);
    }
    else {
        // Http500: Server Error
        $r = new Response("Unknown error occurred.", 500);
    }


    if ($r !== null) {
        $event->setResponse($r);
    }
}
```

Pay attention to this line specifically:

```
$r = new Response("You need to login in order to view this content.", 403);
```

Comment: Why don't you just return a new response in every if/else? You now have an extra if, variable and an empty if :P

Comment: You're right, but is only stripped down version of my exception handler class. I left that empty `if` for a convinience ;)